# rpmlib needed by Epel-Release

Tags: centos, centos6

I currently have a problem with rpmlib(fileDigest) and (PayloadIsXz) I've searched on Google and other websites, including SO without luck (that worked). This is basically what I do:

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

And this is what it spits out:

> [root@XXX ~]# rpm -ivh epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
>   warning: epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature:
>   NOKEY, key ID 0608b895 error: Failed dependencies:
>           rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by epel-release-6-7.noarch
>           rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by epel-release-6-7.noarch

I've searched on Google for those two, but it didn't quite help.

Note: `uname -m` gives "i686" if that's any help.
As well as I run CentOS 6.3

Answer (score 1):

I know it may seem super silly but try:

```
yum upgrade
```

and run the installation again

and instead of using rpm, try a yum:

```
yum localinstall /path/to/your/rpm/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

Yum will try to automatically resolve dependencies, where rpm wont. not 100% sure that will fix it, but definitely something to try :)